# Localization: application crashes when language is changed in simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, localization, ios-simulator

In order to localize my application, I created Localizable.strings for three languages. I didn't need to localize any nib files since I'm not using any in my project. No images were localized, only the strings. In the code, I read the strings using NSLocalizedStrings(@"key", @"comment"). The Localized.strings files use UTF-16 format. The strings look like this: "Projects" = "Projekte";.

When I run the app in the simulator and change the language, my application that's running in the back crashes (SIGKILL). If I rerun the application, I can see that the language has been changed because the label of the Edit button is in German, but all my strings are still in English.

I read many threads about localization and I have three iOS books at home but I still don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Did I forget to set up something else?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because when you change the language of your device, `SpringBoard` kills all the apps so that they will 'load' new language at the next startup. You can't change the system language without your app being killed. It **has** to be killed if you want to save your new language.

Your app doesn't crash. It's being killed (SIGKILL) by iOS.

Comment: Got it! Anyway, as I wrote before, when I re-run my app after it's beein killed, the strings are still in English, even after changing the language to German.

Comment: Are you sure you localized all the strings properly?

Comment: As I wrote, I created the Localized.strings taking this as an orientation: http://rndm-snippets.blogspot.com/2010/11/best-practice-localizationinternational.html (#1 and #2) but with xcode 4. When I see my project in the Finder, there is a lproj folder for every language. Is there anything else that should I consider?

Comment: This is very strange. I got it to work in a very weird way. My lproj folders were called de, en, es. I created duplicates called German, English, Spanish respectively. Re-run the application and it worked. Now I can remove the new folders (German, English, Spanish) and it still works. No idea what happened.

Comment: Maybe cleaning targets helped ;)